Why is “sind” before the noun if the sentence is not a question?
For example: "In dieser Bäckerei sind die Backwaren am frischsten.“ isn’t a question, it’s just saying the baked goods are the freshest, but why isn’t the sentence "In dieser Bäckerei die Backwaren sind am frischsten.“ ?

Why do you think the verb cannot be before the subject?

German is not English and has a much more flexible word order; Nearly the only rule for main clauses is that the (finite) verb comes in the 2nd position. There is no reason the subject cannot be last or anywhere else or has to be before the verb.
In your sentence I marked the single constituents:

(In dieser Bäckerei) (sind) (die Backwaren) (am frischesten)

You can now swap them around as you like - as long as the verb (sind) remains in 2nd position. There are a couple of questions which discuss the different emphasis based on different word order (the quoted one emphasises that 'this bakery' is the topic). Usually the important aspect, the topic, comes first.
Some questions with decent answers on word order which may help you get a feeling for how different word order is used:

Er steigt am Bahnhof um - word order
Die Wortstellung: Zeit, direkt Object und Pronomen. Welche kommt in welchem Ordnung?
Positioning of "nie" in sentences
why is "Mein Bruder spielt Klavier manchmal." wrong?
"Die anzunehmen würde dann wahrscheinlich jeder Kellner ablehnen"-weird word order?
„Ich kann die E-Mail öffnen nicht.“ Wrong


Ich kann die Betonung vor oder hinter das "sind" legen - mit der Reihenfolge sehe ich keinen Zusammenhang. In dieser Bäckerei sind die Backwaren am frischesten. In dieser Bäckerei sind die Backwaren am frischesten.

Unlike English, German does not always put the subject noun, "die Backwaren" in this case, before the verb. English uses what is called the SVO rule, where SVO stands for "subject verb object". For example "I saw a cat." the subject "I" is what is performing the action, the verb "to see" is the action being performed, and the object "a cat" is what the action is operating on. You may put in an adverb, say "yesterday", to include additional information, but its location is more flexible: "Yesterday I saw a cat." or "I saw a cat yesterday." German uses what is called the V2 rule, meaning the positions of most sentence elements, such as the subject, object, and adverbs, are flexible, but the position of the verb is fixed and must come second. So "Ich sah gestern eine Katze.", "Gestern sah ich eine Katze." and "Eine Katze sah ich gestern." are all allowable word orders. German uses word order to convey the importance of each element, and usually puts the "topic", what the speaker thinks the sentence is actually about, as the first element. (I'm simplifying and leaving out a lot of information out here, for example many sentences don't have an object, German does not use the simple past, "sah", as often as English uses the simple past "saw", and that there are changes to verb position in more complex sentences, but giving too much information at once will be more confusing than helpful.)
There are four sentence elements in your example, "die Backwaren" which is the subject, "sind" the verb, "am frischsten" which is a phrase describing the baked goods, and "in dieser Bäckerei" which is a phrase that acts like an adverb. (Unsurprisingly, such a phrase is called an "adverbial phrase".) There isn't an object in this sentence but English still follows the SV part of the rule, and English usually requires a description to follow the verb, but the position of the adverbial phrase is more flexible. So "The baked goods are the freshest in this bakery," and "In this bakery the baked goods are the freshest," are both possible. Similarly, in German there are several possible word orders, but the verb "sind" always comes second, so "Die Backwaren sind am frischsten in dieser Bäckerei." and "In dieser Bäckerei sind die Backwaren am frischsten." are both possible. In the example, the speaker was making a statement about the bakery, even though the grammatical subject is actually the baked good. The reason the second version sounds like a question is that English changes the word order for questions, putting the verb in front of the subject. German does something similar, but it puts the verb in the first position. So the question in German would be "Sind die Backwaren am frischsten in dieser Bäckerei?"
Different languages use different word orders, including all possible permutations of S, V and O, and other more difficult to describe orders. German word order takes some getting used to for English speakers, but in general it's not that complicated once you know that it's not the same as English word order. Even though the rule is different, the result is often the same, since SVO is allowed in German and may be the most frequent order in practice. This may trick learners into believing that German word order the same as English, but it's not and learning what is correct in German is an important step in learning the language.

German is - in marked difference to English - a "V2-language". That means the verb has to come in second position.
(Actually this is the case for main sentences, but these are what those rules describe.)
In your example (I have corrected a few typos):

In dieser Bäckerei sind die Backwaren am frischesten.

The first part of the sentence is an adverbial clause: "in dieser Bäckerei". The second part is the inflected verb: "sind".
Would the sentence be ordered per your suggestion:

In dieser Bäckerei die Backwaren sind am frischesten.

There would be:

"in dieser Bäckerei" (adverbial clause)
"die Backwaren" (subject clause)
"sind" (predicate = verb)

You see, the verb would be in third position, which is not allowed.

As native German speaker, I'd say that the "3rd position wrong" example doesn't sound all that wrong to me. That is, with emphasis In dieser Bäckerei die Backwaren sind am frischesten. (But one may argue that the emphasis makes the combination of this bakery with the particular product one unit. The same would apply to Die Backwaren in dieser Bäckerei sind am frischesten. (Which sounds more usual to me than the example before).
